# Write multiple synthetic API tests for New Relic in a single file

Tags: javascript, terraform, newrelic, newrelic-synthetics

At my organization we have a repository where we write scripts for New Relic for API monitoring. Each team has their own folder, and each file in each folder corresponds to an API. One API can have multiple endpoints. Each file acts as a monitor which is referenced in a TerraForm file.

Now, in one such file, I have written a test for one endpoint already. I want to add tests for more endpoints in the same file. I couldn't find any examples to do so, in the documentation. Is it possible? This is what I have so far:-

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'https://test.api.endpoint.com/v1/test',
  'headers': {
    'x-api-key': 'apikey'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Is it possible to have an array of options (each option contains details of each endpoint), and for each option the callback function would be called?

Answer (score 1):

Yes- I would also recommend using the new `got` library that is bundled into the latest Synthetics runtime (`request` is deprecated). You may also want to report the results back to New Relic via Event API, or handle each URI failure gracefully (try-catch/handled exceptions), that way the whole script doesn't fail if a single uri response fails.

Here is a simple example:

```
var got = require('got');

let urls = ['https://google.com', 'https://newrelic.com'];

async function main() {
  let proms = [];

  await urls.map(url => proms.push(checkUri(url)));

  let results = await Promise.all(proms);
  console.log(results);
}

async function checkUri(uri) {
  var opts = {
    url: uri,
    headers: {}
  };
  let resp = await got.get(opts);

  return resp.statusCode
}

main();
```

This is `Scripted API` type monitor for reference.